# Show multiple display values on interactive report column with multiple values based on LOV (checklist)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to show the display values in the column, but the column is a string with entries like '1:3', '2', '1:2:4', which are the return values based on a LOV with static values.

If I set the column as "Display text (Based on LOV)" it will only work for those entries with one number only, like '3' or '1'.

I thought of normalizing the table, but then I would have a multi table form.
This should be simple, yet I cannot figure out how to do this?

```
    select p.COD,
          UNIDADE_PROPONENTE,
          CAUSA_FUND,
          CAUSAS_RELAC,
          TITULO,
          DESC_SOLUC,
          listagg(a.acao, ';<br><br>') within group (order by null)  as "a.acao",    
          OUTRA_ACAO,
          SUGESTAO,
          SITUACAO
      from TB_PROPOSTA p, TB_ACAO a,
      table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                            connect by level <=regexp_count(p.acao,':') + 1)
                            as sys.odcinumberlist)) x

      where 
        a.cod = regexp_substr(p.acao, '[^:]+', 1, x.column_value)
        and
        (:P2_XUNIDADE_RESPONSAVEL = UNIDADE_PROPONENTE OR :P2_XUNIDADE_RESPONSAVEL IS NULL)
        and   
        (INSTR(':'|| p.acao ||':', ':' || :P2_XACAO || ':') > 0 OR :P2_XACAO IS NULL)
    group by p.cod, p.acao, unidade_proponente, causa_fund, causas_relac, titulo, desc_soluc, outra_acao, sugestao, situacao
    order by p.cod, p.acao;
```

edit: 
Now I either get missing keyword error or sql command not properly ended.
This one gives SQL COMMAND NOT PROPERLY ENDED

```
select p.COD,
       UNIDADE_PROPONENTE,
       CAUSA_FUND,
       CAUSAS_RELAC,
       TITULO,
       DESC_SOLUC,  
       listagg(a.acao, ';<br><br>') within group (order by null) as "a.acao",    
       OUTRA_ACAO,
       SUGESTAO,
       SITUACAO
  from TB_PROPOSTA p
  cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                        connect by level <=regexp_count(p.acao,':') + 1)
                        as sys.odcinumberlist)) x
  left join TB_ACAO.ACAO  

on TB_ACAO.COD = regexp_substr(TB_PROPOSTA.ACAO, '[^:]+', 1, x.column_value) 

    where
        (:P2_XUNIDADE_RESPONSAVEL )= UNIDADE_PROPONENTE OR :P2_XUNIDADE_RESPONSAVEL IS NULL)
        AND
        (:P2_XACAO IN (p.ACAO) OR :P2_XACAO IS NULL)
    group by p.cod, p.acao, unidade_proponente, causa_fund, causas_relac, titulo, desc_soluc, outra_acao, sugestao, situacao
    order by p.cod, p.acao;
```

And if I change the "cross join" to only "join" I get the "Missing keyword (ORA-06550: line 17, column 1: ORA-00905: missing keyword) right before the "where"

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. Are display and return values the same? That's what your first sentence suggests. Why would normalization cause a multi **table** (?) form? Which Apex version do you use? Could you, by any chance, create an example on apex.oracle.com and let us know the credentials so that we'd see it? Or, at lest, post a screenshot? I really have difficulties in imagining what you've described, sorry.

Comment: Sure. It is APEX 5.0.2. About the normalization issue, how would I make the form act on the intersection table without a multi table form?
Here is the [link](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=132646:2:6772279467391::NO:::). The column in question is "Tipo acao". The display values aren't the same as return values. 
So, I want it to display something like "This is display value 1; This is display value 2" instead of "1:2".

Comment: The credentials are cursoaptcu, USER@USER.COM, 123456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for additional explanation.

Would something like this help? My TEST table acts as your report query, while the rest of it splits colon separated values. It is a SQL*Plus example, just to show you what's going on.

```
SQL> with test (situacao, tipo_acao) as
  2  (select 'Aguardando resposta', '1:2:3' from dual union
  3   select 'Aguardando resposta', '5' from dual
  4  )
  5  select
  6    situacao,
  7    'This is value ' || regexp_substr(tipo_acao, '[^:]+', 1, column_value) tipo_acao
  8  from test,
  9    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                        connect by level <= regexp_count(tipo_acao, ':') + 1)
 11                        as sys.odcinumberlist));

SITUACAO            TIPO_ACAO
------------------- ----------------------------------
Aguardando resposta This is value 1
Aguardando resposta This is value 2
Aguardando resposta This is value 3
Aguardando resposta This is value 5

SQL>
```

**[EDIT, after creating Page 5 in your Apex application]**

I think I got it - have a look at Page 5 (created as copy of your page 2 so that I wouldn't spoil it). Its column list is reduced, but you'll get the general idea. Query looks like this; I hope it's OK:

```
select p.cod,
       s.situacao,
       p.tipo_acao,
       listagg(t.acao, ', ') within group (order by null) acao
from tb_proposta p,
     tipo_situacao s,
     vw_unid v,
     tipo_acao t,
     table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                         connect by level <= regexp_count(p.tipo_acao, ':') + 1)
                         as sys.odcinumberlist)) x
where s.cod = p.proposta_status
  and p.cod_vw_unid = v.cod
  and t.cod= regexp_substr(p.tipo_acao, '[^:]+', 1, x.column_value)
group by p.cod, s.situacao, p.tipo_acao
order by p.cod, p.tipo_acao;
```

**[EDIT #2, ANSI outer join]**

This is how you should try to do it. Also, CROSS JOIN and its place in query.

```
select p.cod,
       s.situacao,
       p.tipo_acao,
       listagg(t.acao, ', ') within group (order by null) acao
from tb_proposta p
cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                               connect by level <= regexp_count(p.tipo_acao, ':') + 1)
                               as sys.odcinumberlist)) x 
      join tipo_situacao s   on s.cod = p.proposta_status
      join vw_unid v         on v.cod = p.cod_vw_unid
left  join tipo_acao t  on t.cod = regexp_substr(p.tipo_acao, '[^:]+', 1, x.column_value)
group by p.cod, s.situacao, p.tipo_acao
order by p.cod, p.tipo_acao;
```

Comment: I think that helps. But how would I show the display value of the LOV? f.e.
1 = string
2 = anoter string
Also, would it be possible to aggregate the results, like using listagg()?

Comment: OK then, thank you for credentials. I created Page 5, have a look. I'm going to sleep, it's almost midnight over here. If there's anything else to be done, leave a note - hopefully, I'll have a look tomorrow. Or, if not me, someone else :)

Comment: That's  exactly what I wanted!! You are a genius! Thank you

Comment: If I wanted to use a new line/break line as separator, should I use html tags (and disable escape special chars) or is there another way to do that?

Comment: I've seen that you've already done that and it works as expected. I think that this is the right way to do it.

Comment: So, for some reason it is excluding rows where p.acao is null? I'm going to update my original post with the actual query I'm using in the actual app.

Comment: If you could prepare such data on apex.oracle.com, I'll try to have a look.

Comment: before I do that, I (probably) figured out why it is happening, but I don't know how to fix it. Actually I'm not sure anymore, I thought maybe the   "where 
    a.cod = regexp_substr(p.acao, '[^:]+', 1, x.column_value)" is limiting the search to only the ones that aren't null, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, that smells like an outer join.

Comment: I was thinking about exporting from the actual app and importing into that one but I just added a new row with nothing in "acao" column and the same happens! It only shows rows where "acao" is not null, for some reason. Whenever possible, take a look at both pages, the one you created and the default one.

Comment: See whether outer join (I suggested) does the job; on page 5 it is this line: `and t.cod (+) = regexp_substr(p.tipo_acao, '[^:]+', 1, x.column_value)`

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didn't notice your other reply!

Comment: It did the job. I didn't know (+) was an outer join. Honestly, do you know of any resource on oracle sql, pl/sql and application express? I'm an intern and am struggling with PL/SQL for another project. Also, thank you!

Comment: (+) is an old, Oracle *proprietary* syntax for outer joins. If you're new to all this stuff, perhaps you'd rather get used to use ANSI join (I was lazy to rewrite it all, but you can - just to practice). As of documentation, I always found Oracle 10gR2 page useful (http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/homepage). Why? Because it contains sections you can use. Have a look at "Most popular" and pick "PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference" and "Application Developer's Guide - Fundamentals" - that will get you started. Or, find similar documentation for your Oracle version.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason my last reply wasn't submitted. In the actual app  the outer join didn't work because of an error ora-01417. It says you can only outer join two tables. However, the select I'm using (the one in the original post) is pretty much the same, but with more columns.

Comment: When you use (+) syntax, you can outer join that table to **only** one another table. Oracle will raise an error if you outer join it to yet another table. ANSI join doesn't have that restriction.

Comment: I couldn't really fix that on the actual table. Not sure why it complains tho since it is essentially the same select. Is it possible that the apex version (we use 5.0.2 and oracle apex uses the newest one I guess) is affecting this behaviour?

Comment: (Sorry, went to sleep). I don't think so, those versions are *close* enough, I'd say.

Comment: How would you use ANSI outer join on that example table/report?

Comment: I thoght about using nvl() since when the 'acao' column is null, there is another column 'outra_acao' that should not be null (typed by the user). but it still doesn't work. there are 61 rows and only 59 are being shown.

Comment: Have a look at EDIT #2 in my answer, which shows ho you should try to do it.

Comment: See my edit on OP. It worked fine for the example application, but not on the actual app (which I use slightly different names and dropped 2 tables, VW_UNID and tb_tipo_situacao).

Comment: I'd say that you didn't count open and closed brackets well. Here, you should remove the closed bracket: `where (:P2_XUNIDADE_RESPONSAVEL )=` as it is closed at the end of that OR construct.